# Laravel 5 - How to count total records with joins and group by

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by

I need to count total no. of records coming from database with group by. I don't need count of each set or what group by does by default.

One way i know is to use ->get() on query, but it crashes when i have a lots of record in database.

```
        $orders = Order::where('orders.store_id', $store->id);
        $orders->join('order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id');
        $orders->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id');
        $orders->join('customers', 'order_product.order_id', '=', 'customers.order_id');
        $orders->join('addresses', 'customers.id', '=', 'addresses.customer_id');
        $orders->where('products.status', 1);
        $orders->where('orders.is_deleted', '0');

        if ($keyword) {
            $orders->where(function ($query) use ($keyword, $searchKeyword){
                $query->where('products.title', 'LIKE', $searchKeyword)
                      ->orWhere('orders.order_name', 'LIKE', $searchKeyword);

                if (strtolower($keyword) == 'enabled') {
                    $query->orWhere('orders.status', '=', 1);
                }elseif (strtolower($keyword) == 'disabled') {
                    $query->orWhere('orders.status', '=', 0);
                }

                return $query;
            });
        }

        $orders->groupby('orders.id');

        // Total orders
        $totalOrders = count($orders->get());

        $orders->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)->skip($startFrom)->take($itemsPerPage);
        $orders = $orders->select([
            'orders.id',
            'orders.order_name',
            'products.title',
            'products.handle',
            'products.id as product_id',
            'orders.status'
        ])->get();
```

Comment: you have to do two separate query  for getting the total records

Comment: I assume you want to paginate `$orders`. Did you try `$orders->paginate($itemsPerPage)` instead of `$order->skip()->take()->get()`? `paginate()` already returns collection.

Comment: Yes, pagination is what i need. I am using dataTable of jquery for pagination. Is it possible with paginate?

Comment: `$orders->paginate($itemsPerPage)` Gives you exact same results as `$orders->skip($startFrom)->take($itemsPerPage)->get()`. There's a slight difference, because `Model::get()` gives you `Collection` instance, while `Model::paginate()` returns [LengthAwarePaginator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php). However you can iterate over both. Please see [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination) on laravel docs

Comment: Thanks @Skysplit It worked for me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @NiveshSaharan You're welcome! :) I posted my comments as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy from my comments:

I assume you want to paginate `$orders`.

```
$orders->paginate($itemsPerPage)
```

Gives you exact same results as

```
$orders->skip($startFrom)->take($itemsPerPage)->get().
```

There's a slight difference, because `Model::get()` gives you Collection instance, while `Model::paginate()` returns [LengthAwarePaginator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php). However you can iterate over both.
Please see [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination) on laravel docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code with @Skysplit help:

```
        // Get orders
        $orders = $store->orders();

        $orders->join('order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id');
        $orders->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id');
        $orders->join('customers', 'order_product.order_id', '=', 'customers.order_id');
        $orders->join('addresses', 'customers.id', '=', 'addresses.customer_id');
        $orders->where('products.status', 1);
        $orders->where('orders.is_deleted', '0');

        if ($keyword) {
            $orders->where(function ($query) use ($keyword, $searchKeyword){
                $query->where('products.title', 'LIKE', $searchKeyword)
                      ->orWhere('orders.order_name', 'LIKE', $searchKeyword);

                if (strtolower($keyword) == 'enabled') {
                    $query->orWhere('orders.status', '=', 1);
                }elseif (strtolower($keyword) == 'disabled') {
                    $query->orWhere('orders.status', '=', 0);
                }

                return $query;
            });
        }

        $orders->groupby('orders.id');

        $orders->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection);
        $orders = $orders->select([
            'orders.id',
            'orders.order_name',
            'products.title',
            'products.handle',
            'products.id as product_id',
            'orders.status'
        ])->paginate($itemsPerPage);

        // Total orders
        $totalOrders = $orders->total();
```

Hope it would help someone.